# uploading problems of an image

Tags: php, upload

it is such that I must also have build up that it will upload a picture to server, but it appears with the error that makes it not possible to proceed or what to say? hmm

activate.php **her**

```
<input type="file" name="file" />
```

activate_updater.php **her**

```
<?php include ("include/database/db.php");
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
session_start();

        $pb = null;
        include("class.upload.php");
        $handle = new Upload($_FILES['profilbillede']);

        if($handle->uploaded){
                //lidt mere store billeder
                $handle->image_resize = true;
                $handle->image_ratio_y = true;
                $handle->image_x = 220;
                $handle->Process("profil/store");
                    //til profil billede lign..
                    $handle->image_resize = true;
                    $handle->image_ratio_crop = true;
                    $handle->image_y = 75;
                    $handle->image_x = 75;
                    $handle->Process("profil");                
            $pb = $handle->file_dst_name;

                echo 'Billedet: '.$pb.'<br>';
                echo "Dit billede blev upload<br>";
        }else{
                $pb = 'bruger_intet.png';
            }

    if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare('UPDATE `brugere` SET `rank`=2, `katogori`=?, `djnavn`=?, `profilbillede`=?, `profiltekst`=?, `facebook`=?, `pris`=?, `booking`=?, `mobil`=? WHERE `code`=?'))
    {

        $stmt->bind_param('iiiiiiiis', $katogori, $djnavn, $profilbillede, $profiltekst, $facebook, $pris, $booking, $mobil, $g_code);
        //fra input ting ting..
        $katogori = $_POST["kategori"];
        $djnavn = $_POST["djnavn"];
        $profilbillede = $_POST["file"];
        $profiltekst = $_POST["profiltekst"];
        $facebook = $_POST["facebook"];
        $pris = $_POST["pris"];
        $booking = $_POST["booking"];
        $mobil = $_POST["mobil"];
        $g_code = $_SESSION["code"];

        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();

        header("Location: http://.....dk/logind/");

    }
    else
    {
        echo 'Der opstod en fejl i erklÃ¦ringen: ' . $mysqli->error;
    }
?>
```

**so here comes the error here?**

Notice: Undefined index: file in /home/jesperbo/public_html/,,,.dk/activate_updater.php on line 37

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/jesperbo/public_html/,,,.dk/activate_updater.php:24) in /home/jesperbo/public_html/,,.dk/activate_updater.php on line 48

*here comes the problem*

```
$profilbillede = $_POST["file"];
```

and here

```
echo 'Billedet: '.$pb.'<br>';
```

and here

```
header("Location: http://....dk/logind/");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like the error message says, you can't send headers after you output text.

```
header('....')
```

has to come *before* any echo commands.

Comment: what do you think such a hero with that? I do not understand it completely?

Comment: what do not you understand? so then I can try to explain to me?

Answer (score 0):

You can't send headers after the headers have already been sent. Modify your code so headers are before any output, including white space

Comment: Basically, `headers()` MUST come before ANY output. You can read more about it here http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Comment: I do not quite understand what the output

Comment: Output includes anything you write to the page using `echo` or `print_r` or any other command. It also includes any characters before the opening `<?php` tag, INCLUDING spaces or blank lines.